# How to mock the toastr in Angular?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, rxjs

I'm not sure I'm writing a good title regarding this problem or not.
How to mock and bypass into this 2 red line?

```
fit('Should call the sub entity list', () => {

    expect(component.subentity.length).toBe(0);

    spyOn(subentitysvc, 'getSubEntityList').and.returnValue(of(modelMock));
    component.getSubEntityList(1);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(subentitysvc.getSubEntityList).toHaveBeenCalled();

    spyOn(toastr, 'error').and.callFake(() => { });

})
```

Answer (score 1):

A long as you use jasmine, you can spy on `toastr.error` method:

```
spyOn(toastr, 'error').and.callThrough();
```

Instead of `callThrough` you can also use `returnValue` or `callFake`.

Comment: actually I have try call fake, but the problem is after the callfake I'm not sure how to proceed the next step :(

Comment: What is expected behavior of this mock. Though I know `error` method returns `void`

Comment: What is problem? Do you have an error? Plase try move last spy above `component.getSubEntityList(1);`

Comment: It give me this error message.

Error: <spyOn> : could not find an object to spy upon for error()
Usage: spyOn(<object>, <methodName>)

Comment: you have `this.toastr` in component, so in test it sohuld be `component.toastr`, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm expecting you haven't setup the toastr service properly in your test so have a look at the following for changes. You need to spy **before you create your component** for it to work as well.

I have moved this line `spyOn(TestBed.get(ToastrService), 'error');` up and assuming that your toaster service is called `ToastrService`.

```js
fit('Should call the sub entity list', () => {

    expect(component.subentity.length).toBe(0);

    spyOn(subentitysvc, 'getSubEntityList').and.returnValue(of(modelMock));
    spyOn(TestBed.get(ToastrService), 'error');
    component.getSubEntityList(1);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(subentitysvc.getSubEntityList).toHaveBeenCalled();

})
```

Hope this helps.
P.s. I'd recommend having only one assertion per test as it makes it easier to diagnose problems. So your first line should probably be `component.subentity = []`.